# Mathematica 11.0.1 hangs calling InputForm[r] when ";" is missing in above line

Tags: input-forms

This one is *really* strange.  Mathematica just hangs when I call `InputForm[r]` where `r` happened to be the solution obtained from `DSolve`, and this only happens if the line before did not have ";" on it.

The hang is severe, in the sense, it eats more and more RAM and the PC becomes very slow.

Why does this happen? It looks like having the expression displayed in the notebook affects `InputForm`. This also seems to happen with this particular expression. Not with others I tried this on.

Here is the code. *This version hangs*

```
ClearAll[x, y];
ode = (y'[x])^4 + f[x] (y[x] - a)^3 (y[x] - b)^3 == 0;
r = TimeConstrained[DSolve[ode, y[x], x], 100]
r0 = InputForm[r]
```

Now, this version below do *not* hang. The only difference is that now I added a ";" to the line above the last one, which causes `r` not to show in the input notebook. No other difference.

```
ClearAll[x, y];
ode = (y'[x])^4 + f[x] (y[x] - a)^3 (y[x] - b)^3 == 0;
r = TimeConstrained[DSolve[ode, y[x], x], 100]; (*notice ";" *)
r0 = InputForm[r]
```

Why is having ";" there makes `InputForm` not hang, but removing it makes it hang? It does not matter if `InputForm[r]` is called from same cell, or difference cell. It will hang if there is no ";"

### Screen shot showing the hang

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Screen shot showing *no* hang

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Version 11.0.1 on windows 7, 64 bit

Comment: Does evaluating just `InverseFunction[-((4*
       Hypergeometric2F1[1/4, 3/4, 
        5/4, (a - #1)/(a - b)]*(a - #1)^(1/4)*
             ((-b + #1)/(a - b))^(3/4))/(b - #1)^(3/4)) & ]` hang for you?

Comment: @ilian Yes. The command you show hangs. But `InputForm` is not really supposed to do any evaluation of expression, per help. Your command has been running for 5 minutes so far. it is still running. Is this command not supposed to hang? Thanks for looking at it.